# Creating Snippets of ViewPage ServerSide Code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, code-snippets

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC Project and I have a number of node snippets that I need to insert into multiple pages. I would very much like to know whether or not it is possible to have a snippet of code that can be placed in an external file and called from within a ViewPage. In a way this would be similar to calling a class from a class.cs file.

Here is an example snippet of code:

```
<% Amazon.ECS.Model.Cart leftCart = ViewData["leftCart"] as Amazon.ECS.Model.Cart %>
<strong>Total: </strong>
<%= leftCart.SubTotal.FormattedPrice%><br />
<strong>Items: </strong>
<%= leftCart.CartItems.CartItem.Count%>
<center>
<a href="<%= leftCart.PurchaseURL %>">
<img style="float: right; margin-top: 20px;" src="/../../Content/Images/checkout.gif"
/></a></center>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use view user controls. They are essentially `ascx` files and behave roughly the same as their Web forms counterparts. The primary difference is that they inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl` instead of `System.Web.UI.UserControl`.

You can either embed them using `<% @Register %>` tags and `<prefix:Name runat="server" />` or using `Html.RenderPartial` method.